# Access the current HttpContext from a ILogger

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET Core 1.0, I have a custom implementation of the `ILoggerProvider` and `ILogger` interfaces. I would like to be able to access the HttpContext from the `Log` method.

It seems I need to inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` into the custom `ILogger`, but can't find how to do that. The `ILoggerProvider` object is created at startup, and the `CreateLogger` method doesn't allow for dependency injection.

Is there a simple way to use dependency injection with `ILogger`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example

`Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddCustomLogger(serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
        // 
    }
```

Custom Logger:

```
public class CustomLogProvider : ILoggerProvider
{

    private readonly Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public CustomLogProvider(Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _filter = filter;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomLogger(categoryName, _filter, _accessor);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class CustomLogger : ILogger
{
    private string _categoryName;
    private Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public CustomLogger(string categoryName, Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _filter = filter;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return (_filter == null || _filter(_categoryName, logLevel));
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (formatter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formatter));
        }

        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        message = $"{ logLevel }: {message}";

        if (exception != null)
        {
            message += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + exception.ToString();
        }
        if(_accessor.HttpContext != null) // you should check HttpContext 
        {
            message += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        }
        // your implementation

    }

}
public static class CustomLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggerFactory AddCustomLogger(this ILoggerFactory factory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
                                          Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter = null)
    {
        factory.AddProvider(new CustomLogProvider(filter, accessor));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Although** above way works, i would prefer to implement custom `IRequestLogger` instead of injecting `HttpContextAccessor`. Implementation is like below(it is not tested):

```
public interface IRequestLogger<T>
{
    void Log(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string message); // you can change this
}

public class RequestLogger<T> : IRequestLogger<T>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public RequestLogger(ILogger<T> logger, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string message)
    {
        Func<object, Exception, string> _messageFormatter = (object state, Exception error) =>
        {
            return state.ToString();
        };
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, 0, new FormattedLogValues(message), null, _messageFormatter);
    }
}
```

And simple usage:

```
public class LogType
{

}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
     services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRequestLogger<>), typeof(RequestLogger<>));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     loggerFactory.AddConsole(true);
     app.Run(async (context) =>
     {
         var requestLogger = context.RequestServices.GetService<IRequestLogger<LogType>>();
         requestLogger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, 11, "<message>");
         //
     });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted my answer and then saw you beat me to it.  This is more complete anyway, so I voted it up.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this code, but I believe the approach will be something like the following.

In your `Startup.cs` class, register a HttpContextAccessor by adding the following line to the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Then, add an additional parameter for the `IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor` to the Configure method (still inside `Startup.cs`), something like:

```
public void Configure(
                      IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
                      IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
```

Inside this `Configure` method, you can add now invoke an extension method on the logger factory to create your custom log provider, something like:

```
loggerFactory.AddMyCustomProvider(httpContextAccessor);
```

where the extension method (that you need to create) will be something like:

```
public static class MyCustomLoggerExtensions
  {
    public static ILoggerFactory AddMyCustomProvider(
        this ILoggerFactory factory, 
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
      factory.AddProvider(new MyCustomLoggerProvider(httpContextAccessor));
      return factory;
    }
  }
```