# How do I get the unique id (like requestid from Serilog) of a request in my implementation ILogger?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, ilogger

I have a separate microservice which get HTTP messages (JSON) from another microservices, logging them (messages) with Serilog and sends them to a graylog (GELF). One message - one log, example:

1. Message: "Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44312/api/home  "
   From: "WebApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
   2)Message: "Log example text message!!!"
   From: "WebApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
   ....

I want to add a "request ID" field for every message that will be sent from other microservices without using Serilog in other microservices. How can I get it in MyLogger class?

First and second messages - are the same request but my "logging-microservce" get them as two different messages and the serilog inside this service (("logging-microservce" ) will process them as two other requests with different request id.

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public MyLogger()
    {
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        if (exception != null)
        {
            message = $"{exception.GetType()}: {exception.Message}";
        }

        var logMessageModel = new LogMessageModel(logLevel, message, **REQUEST_ID???????,** Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName, exception?.StackTrace);
        string selectionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logMessageModel);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(selectionString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:44353/api/logging", stringContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Serilog confings in my logging-service:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Graylog", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Override": {
        "LoggingExample.Handler": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Graylog",
        "Args": {
          "hostnameOrAddress": "127.0.0.1",
          "port": "1514",
          "transportType": "Tcp"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Centralized logging application"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

.NET Core 2.2

Comment: "My logger" is a class which I used in other microservices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364135/access-the-current-httpcontext-from-a-ilogger answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Correlation Id to track your requests.
A Correlation ID, also known as a Transit ID, is a unique identifier value that is attached to requests and messages that allow reference to a particular transaction or event chain. A Correlation ID is defined as a non-standard HTTP header and is part of the Java Messaging Service (JMS).

Here you have a link with the best practices for Serilog.

https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices/